# How to test if two sparse arrays are (almost) equal?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I want to check if two sparse arrays are (almost) equal. Whereas for numpy arrays you can do:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ones(200)
np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(a, a)
```

This does not work for sparse arrays, which I can understand (either returns error `AttributeError: ravel not found` for smaller matrices or errors related to size of array). Is there a scipy equivalent to test sparse matrices? I could convert my sparse matrices are to dense matrices and use the numpy testing function, but sometimes this is not possible due to (memory/size) constraints. E.g.:

```
from scipy import sparse

b = sparse.rand(80000,8000,density=0.01)
type(b)  # <class 'scipy.sparse.coo.coo_matrix'>
c = b.toarray()  # ValueError: array is too big; `arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize` is larger than the maximum possible size.
```

Is it possible to test these larger scipy arrays for equality, or should I test smaller samples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that are we are not concerned with the non-zeros in one that array that might be within the tolerance value, we can simply get the row, col indices and the corresponding values and look for exact matches between the indices, while `allclose()` match for the values.

Hence, the implementation would be -

```
from scipy.sparse import find

def allclose(A, B, atol = 1e-8):

    # If you want to check matrix shapes as well
    if np.array_equal(A.shape, B.shape)==0:
        return False

    r1,c1,v1 = find(A)
    r2,c2,v2 = find(B)
    index_match = np.array_equal(r1,r2) & np.array_equal(c1,c2)

    if index_match==0:
        return False
    else:  
        return np.allclose(v1,v2, atol=atol)
```

Here's another with `nonzero` and `data` methods to replace `find` function -

```
def allclose_v2(A, B, atol = 1e-8):
    # If you want to check matrix shapes as well
    if np.array_equal(A.shape, B.shape)==0:
        return False

    r1,c1 = A.nonzero()
    r2,c2 = B.nonzero()

    lidx1 = np.ravel_multi_index((r1,c1), A.shape)
    lidx2 = np.ravel_multi_index((r2,c2), B.shape)

    sidx1 = lidx1.argsort()
    sidx2 = lidx2.argsort()

    index_match = np.array_equal(lidx1[sidx1], lidx2[sidx2])
    if index_match==0:
        return False
    else:  
        v1 = A.data
        v2 = B.data        
        V1 = v1[sidx1]
        V2 = v2[sidx2]        
        return np.allclose(V1,V2, atol=atol)
```

We can short-circuit at few places to speed it up further. On performance, I am focusing more at cases where only the values differ.

Comment: Might want to put that `np.allclose` behind `if index_match:` .  If `v1` and `v2` are different lengths it will throw an error.

Comment: if I understand correctly you suggest to compare if the row and column indeces are identical and if the values are close. I like the idea, however if stuggle to see how find() works on your example (it throws an error is I try to use it). Is it identical to using `A.row`, `A.col`, `A.data` directly in the comparison statements?

Comment: @BartDur Guessing it needed an IF to compare for lengths being equal first. Edited.

Comment: @DanielF Thanks. Needed improvement there.

Comment: wait... the `find()` you are using is [scipy.sparse.find()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.find.html)? That was not clear to me first, but now it all makes sense, thanks!

Comment: I'm sure there's a good reason you're soritng in your second method, but I can't tell for the life of me how that would speed anything up.

Comment: @DanielF Well that `find` is super slow. So, even after so much of processing, it seems to be worth the extra effort.

Comment: Ahh, but `nonzero` doesn't always return the coordinates in sorted order.  Gotcha.

Comment: Why not onvert `A` and `B` to a `sparse` format with a rigid indexing scheme like `csr` and then use `indices` and `indptr` to compare?

Comment: or do `sidx1 = np.lexsort((r1, c1))`

Comment: You might want to set `equal_nan=True` for the `np.allclose` call